# Button width and radius with react native android

Tags: react-native

HI I needed help with my code regarding my button, It just won't increase it's width or have any border radius applied to it even a border color wont work. 
Can you tell me what is the mistake in my code?

Here is my code:

```
        const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
        <View style={{width: '100%', height: '20%',justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
                    <Button 
                    width={150}
                    style={{ 
                    borderColor:'red',
                    borderRadius:30,
                    justifyContent: 'center', 
                    alignItems:'center',}}
                    title="LOGIN"
                    color="black"
                    onPress = { () => 
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                    /> 
        </View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React native Button has limited prop. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button
You need to use TouchableOpacity or TouchableOpacityWithoutFeedback like this

```
<TouchableOpacity 
                style={{ 
                width:150
                borderColor:'red',
                borderRadius:30,
                justifyContent: 'center', 
                alignItems:'center'
                }}
                onPress = { () => 
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                > 
    <Text style={{color:'#000000'}}>LOGIN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that however what I used is that I nested my button inside a View so that I can manipulate it's style.